# How do I generate a list of post-synaptic gene markers that will guide me in my search for these markers in intestinal stem cells?

Tags: scrnaseq, gene, phylogenetics, gene-expression

I would like to generate a list of gene markers that represent post-synaptic related genes. I will then use this list to search through single cell sequencing data, in order to assess whether certain cell types express post-synaptic related genes. I think there might be a way to get this list of gene markers from NCBI.

Thank you!

Comment: something like this ? https://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/geneset_page.jsp?geneSetName=REACTOME_NEUROTRANSMITTER_RECEPTOR_BINDING_AND_DOWNSTREAM_TRANSMISSION_IN_THE_POSTSYNAPTIC_CELL

Comment: Yes! i think so. Thanks for sharing. I didn't know about this database!